# How to delete duplicates but keep one when all tuples are identical in duplicates and original? In postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates, sql-delete

Suppose we have below table.
How to delete 2 duplicates and keep one? My code deletes all of them.

```
+----+-------+
| ID | NAME  |
+----+-------+
|  2 | ARK   |
|  3 | CAR   |
|  9 | PAR   |
|  9 | PAR   |
|  9 | PAR   |
+----+-------+
```

Comment: What is your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, your table should have a unique ID. If not then you can use ctid as a dummy unique ID field as the below query.

ctid represents the physical location of the row version within its table. Note that although the ctid can be used to locate the row version very quickly, a row’s ctid will change if it is updated or moved by VACUUM FULL. Therefore ctid is useless as a long-term row identifier. But it does the job here.

```
 delete from my_table a using my_table b where a=b and a.ctid < b.ctid;
```

DB fiddle link - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=4888d519e125dc095496a57477a60b9f

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using `deletion by row_number`

```
    Delete from table t1 where 1<(
   Select rn from ( select id, name, 
   row_number() over (partition by id, name
  order by id) rn from table)
```